# svg.js v3 and svg.panzoom.js does not work with rollup (nor webpack/parcel)

Tags: svg.js

When I use **svg.js v3** in combination with **svg.panzoom.js**, I get the following error (when importing svg.panzoom.js):

```
'extend' is not exported by node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.min.js

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module-

import { Svg, on, off, extend, Matrix, Box } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'
```

Are there any examples using svg.js v3 + plugins + rollup (webpack/parcel)
I tried transpiling it to esm / cjs / iife / umd (all same error)

```
// this line is ok and is working
import SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg.js';
// this line gives the error
import '@svgdotjs/svg.panzoom.js/src/svg.panzoom.js';
```

Comment: We are working on fixing this issue soon. Its a mistake on our site!

Comment: The issue was fixed right now. A simple `import '@svgdotjs/svg.panzoom.js'` shall do it :). Dont forget to update your dependencies!

Comment: everything works perfect. Thanks